# Filter Field in List by boolean value in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, view

I had help filtering a Foreach loop in my view and I figured I would use that reasoning to now filter a field using the same logic.  I need this field to show the last TicketNoteDate that has a PublicFlag == true.  The code compiles but it crashes when I try to run it.  Here is the code I tried:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TicketNotes.OrderBy(t => t.TicketNoteDate).Where(t => t.PublicFlag == true).Last().TicketNoteDate)
```

and here is the error I received:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

If I remove this code:

```
.Where(t => t.PublicFlag == true)
```

then it works except for of course the filtering out non public notes.

Comment: Could it be that there is not item with PublicFlag== true?

Comment: after filtering may be records count is 0 so it will throw error

Comment: Not related but you should put `.Where()` before `Orderby()` - much more efficient.

Comment: What happens with .Where(t => t.PublicFlag == false)?

Comment: Karl Kieninger it was because there were times that a ticket would not have any public notes as another suggested.  That in itself was an error I fixed for all tickets going in the future but I never fixed the old tickets I created as tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TicketNotes.Where(t => t.PublicFlag == true).OrderByDescending(t => t.TicketNoteDate).First().TicketNoteDate)
```